# Regex for a record that starts with a number and ends with a particular string

Tags: php, regex

I get some results using file_get_contents like below.

```
30049988.html" >Title1
297816.html" >Title2
2979922.html" >Title3
29736.html" >Title4
22833.html" >Title5
```

I want to remove the ugly part (number.html" >) and get the titles only, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Is that HTML you're processing?

Comment: I was trying to process HTML in my last question but gave up, found another way to echo the results using strip_tags()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `preg_replace` function.

```
preg_replace('~.*?>~', '', $string);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eG7cI3/2)

`.*?` will do a non-greedy match of zero or more characters.

OR

```
preg_replace('~^\d+\.html" >~', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

The preg_replace method will work, but to answer the original question for anyone else wondering.

```
<?php
$string = <<<EOF
30049988.html" >Title1
297816.html" >Title2
2979922.html" >Title3
29736.html" >Title4
22833.html" >Title5
EOF;
preg_match_all('~[^>]+>([^\\n]+)$~smU', $string, $matches);
if (!isset($matches[1])) {
  echo 'No results found ..'. PHP_EOL;
  exit;
}

foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
  echo $match.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cat try this regex.

```
(?=T)(\w+)
```

***How this works***

1. `(?=T)` - This is a positive lookahead. It checks if the pattern starts with `T` and only then proceeds next.
2. `(\w+)` - This groups all word characters from `T`.

***Output:***

```
Title1
Title2
Title3
Title4
Title5
```

[Here is the regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/gJ8bW5/1).